# IOS 8.1.3 - Return to Inbox After Deleting

Tags: email, ios, iphone

After deleting an open e-mail, is there a way to return to the inbox by default instead of opening the next e-mail in the list?

Comment: I'll take a month of silence as a "no."

Comment: You can always self-answer that No is the answer and select it (or choose the answer that says no. If something changes or someone comes up with a maybe or yes later, you can always change the "correct answer" mark to the newer information.

Answer (score -3):

I kno. I want tha same thing. Don't think it can be done.

Comment: @Mattia I disagree - the answer this person is saying is you can't do this. The asker asked a yes/no question and this person is saying no. perhaps you can answer yes and document it better than Toretto? Or you could improve this post with a link or some research explaining in more detail the No answer.